# Passing env vars with ssh command

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I have this command:

```
ssh -Y \
    ubuntu@ec2-doop.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com \
    -i "$HOME/.interos/pem/latest/interos-test.pem"
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx \
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx  exec /bin/bash
```

when I `echo "$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"`  I get empty vars. How do I pass these vars with the command line? Or just source the vars from a file on my local machine?

I tried using this too:

```
 'export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIA5JN65TLJSSBQKGVX export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=MvcJZy24CS/ZMA1o2/5en/9kU74vCUm/5QbaWzyC  exec /bin/bash'
```

that didn't work either

Comment: Try this: `export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yourkey && export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=youraccesskey && ssh -Y ...`

Comment: Give `ec2-doop.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` a role in the AWS console, so you don't have to send your credentials.

Comment: @WalterA I see, so the role can store the ssh creds somehow? can you explain more?

Comment: The original command works for me (after modifying it for a different ssh server). How exactly are you testing it? Try using `env | grep AWS` instead of `echo`.

Comment: You need the credentials on your local server for connecting to the ec2. When you want the connect from your ec2 to another aws service (database or S3 or ..) you can identify yourself with your personal credentials (thats why you are trying to transfer your keys). Another possibility is using IAM in the AWS console and assign the rights for accessing the db/s3/.. to the ec2 server. When you have 10 servers that need to have 5 special rights, it is easier to combine these 5 rights in one role, and assign this role to the 10 servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
ssh -Y \
ubuntu@ec2-doop.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com \
-i "$HOME/.interos/pem/latest/interos-test.pem" \
'export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx && \
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx && \
exec /bin/bash'
```

Comment: `ssh ... 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxx exec /bin/bash'` is almost exactly identical (putting assignments in the same line with a simple command exports environment variables for the duration of that one command). As such, this has rather more syntax than it needs.